# Error: invalid_client with Google Apps API OAuth2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-developers-console

I am using Google Apps API for my application with OAuth2. ,but I get an error.

```
Error: invalid_client

no support email
```

Request Details
That’s all we know.

Answer (score 7):

In the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) make sure that you have added a `product name` and an `email address` under.  Apps & auths -> consent screen.

[image]

**Update:**  This shouldn't be to much of a problem anymore.  Google made a change in the [console](https://console.developers.google.com) that wont let you save anything until you have updated these items.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Product name & Email are both set (email was selected from dropdown). Saved & revisited "Consent screen" to confirm; all there. Followed http://updraftplus.com/support/configuring-google-drive-api-access-in-updraftplus/

Comment: I suggest you contact updraftplus support for help, since its not your application posting the code you are having a problem with isn't going to help.

Comment: Make sure you created Client ID for web application  and that it points to the files on your site.  I have tested and it does work.

Comment: @DalmTo Where is consent screen please ?

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com  (your project) left hand side under  Apps & auths -> consent screen

Answer (score 7):

If you create OAuth credentials **BEFORE** you set the support email address in the consent screen, then it appears that you will always get this error, even after setting the support email.

I resolved this by setting the support email, and then recreating all necessary OAuth ids in the credentials page.

Comment: I edited the URL, saved, then edited it back for similar effect.

Answer (score 6):

In [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) turn **Gmail API** on.

GDC > Dashboard > Use Google APIs > Google Apps APIs > Gmail API

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are set up the **setDeveloperKey** with your **EMAIL ADDRESS** offred in Google Console whe you create a **Client ID for web application**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and the solution was:

- Set my email
- Recreate the keys
- Activate Google API+ from API Library

Answer (score 0):

1) Fill out the info **email address and produce name** as well as other details in the '**consent**' screen on google's console when you generate the keys.

2) And make sure when you copy paste the **ClientID and ClientSecret** code from google to your workspace (IDE), there might be ***some unwanted spaces inbetween***

Check with the google console and remove it.

Hope this helps,

--happy coding!