# google Auth2 401. That’s an error. Error: invalid_client no support email

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm trying to connect to google api with OAuth2, but I get this error:

```
401. That’s an error.    
Error: invalid_client    
no support email
```

I do search  find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775972/error-invalid-client-with-google-apps-api-oauth2) for example you have added a product name and an email address under. Apps & auths -> consent screen.

> but what is the consent screen ?
>    Is There any other solution to
>   resolve the problem ?

Comment: I already saw this but they talk about consent screen i don't know where and what  is this creen :(

Comment: Read the answer I just uploaded a picture for you.  The answer to this question is still the same as that one.  So its a duplicate.

Comment: Yes i saw it thank's i will try this solution,

Comment: Response is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775972/error-invalid-client-with-google-apps-api-oauth2#23776562