# How to resolve Invalid client, OAuth client was not found

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst, gmail-api, google-signin

We are trying to login my worklight hybrid mobile sample application with any google account.

Below screen shot Steps for we creating the google gmail API and creating OAuth 2.0 client IDs

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>LoginSN</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <!--
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
      -->
      <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
      <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
      <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"/></script>
      <meta name="manifest" content="./google-services.json" />
        
   <script type="text/javascript">
   
    var CLIENT_ID = '<349212001841-2n2vc099on8m0qkms753bdbr60ecnf5o.apps.googleusercontent.com>';
   
    var SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' ];
   
    function checkAuth() {
     gapi.auth.authorize({
      'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
      'scope' : SCOPES.join(' '),
      'immediate' : true
     }, handleAuthResult);
    }
   
    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
     var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
     if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadGmailApi();
     } else {
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
     }
    }
   
    function handleAuthClick(event) {
     gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id : CLIENT_ID,
      scope : SCOPES,
      immediate : false
     }, handleAuthResult);
     return false;
    }
   
    function loadGmailApi() {
     gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);
    }
   
    function listLabels() {
     var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
      'userId' : 'me'
     });
   
     request.execute(function(resp) {
      var labels = resp.labels;
      appendPre('Labels:');
   
      if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
       for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var label = labels[i];
        appendPre(label.name)
       }
      } else {
       appendPre('No Labels found.');
      }
     });
    }
   
   function appendPre(message) {
     var pre = document.getElementById('output');
     var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
     pre.appendChild(textContent);
    }
   </script>

</head>
  
     <body style="display: none;">
     
      <div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <h1 id="fb-welcome"></h1>
     <label for="text">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unL">
     <label for="text">Password:</label><input type="password" name="text" id="pwdL">
     <a href="#dashboardPage" data-role="button" id="buttonLn">LOGIN</a>
     <a href="#registrationPage" data-role="button" id="buttonRe">REGISRASTION</a>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" id="buttonF" onclick="fblogin()">via Facebook Login</a>
     <!-- <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">via Google Login</a> -->
     <!-- <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" onclick="callGoogle()">via Google Login</a>  -->
     
     <!--  <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" onclick="login('google')">via Google Login</a>  -->
     <div id="authorize-div" >
       <span>Authorize access to Gmail API</span>
       <a href="#" data-role="button" id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">via Google Login</a>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
           
      <div data-role="page" id="dashboardPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick='Logout();'>LogOut</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <script src="js/hello.js"></script>
      <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
      
     </body>
</html>
```

[image: Steps for we creating the google gmail API and creating OAuth 2.0 client IDs]

No error in the error log, just the page load error quoted here.
We got error like this screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 implies that you have an invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid. Try to refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, please direct through the [OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth). Maybe you also need to recreate the `client id` in Developers Console. Make sure to have Google+ API enabled.

Check these related SO questions:

- [Error: invalid_client with Google Apps API OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775972/error-invalid-client-with-google-apps-api-oauth2)

  > If you create OAuth credentials BEFORE you set the support email address in the consent screen, then it appears that you will always get this error, even after setting the support email. I resolved this by setting the support email, and then recreating all necessary OAuth ids in the credentials page.
- [invalid_client in google oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2)

  > Set/change your product name, I had this issue until I created a product name as same as project name. The product name can be set in the Consent screen section of the Google Developers Console for your project. Look under APIs & auth in the left navigation and select Consent screen. You need also to set your email address in the box above the product name.

Comment: abielita i modified the question please find it. error is not resolved . i am followed what ever you said.