# Google OAuth2: Error 401 - invalid_client

Tags: heroku, google-oauth

I am deploying an app on Heroku that uses Google OAuth2.  When I test the app, I go to the auth url (/auth/google) and I see the following error message (note that I replaced domain name with *** just for posting here:

> 401. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_client
>
> The OAuth client was not found.
>
> Request Details response_type=code
>   redirect_uri=https://****.com/auth/google/callback scope=profile email
>   client_id=process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID That’s all we know.

I have looked at the following questions before posting and have been trying to debug for several hours:

[Error: invalid_client with Google Apps API OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775972/error-invalid-client-with-google-apps-api-oauth2)

[invalid_client in google oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166848/invalid-client-in-google-oauth2)

I have tried to do the following:

1. Ensure there are no spaces before and after the values in Heroku
2. The consent screen in Google Console has the name and email address completed
3. I have renamed the app within Google Console
4. I have deleted the key/value from Heroku and re-created

Despite all this, I am unable to fix this.  Any ideas on what I maybe missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is in the question.

Google can't find any reference to your client, which is identified by the client_id in the URL. Instead of a valid client_id (which looks something like "40740878192.apps.googleusercontent.com") you have given a client_id of "process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID". It looks like a bug in your code that instead of using process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as a variable, you have used it as a literal.

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid! Looks like that was indeed the issue - I had accidentally wrapped the variable in double quotes.  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, I have followed the same steps as the poster of this issue, but my client id is actually a client id, not a string that says "CLIENT_ID".  Any ideas?

Comment: In my case I provide text inside devise.rb not actual env key. Thank you!